# How to add calculated column to existing table that would ignore selected value in a slicer Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to add calculated column that would ignore values selected in a slicer:

I tried:

```
all users = ALL(Sheet1[UserName])
```

But it gives me an error: `A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculated column cannot be affected by a slicer but that's not what you seem to be referring to.

It appears you are trying to create a visual that lists all the users. For this, you can put `Username` on a table visual and disable the filtering from the slicer by going to the Format tab and clicking [Edit interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions).

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand you correctly, You have to use ALL() Function by
>   creating new table Under the modelling tab

[image]